# Significato di "sacramento" in questo contesto

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Diceria dell'untore*, di Gesualdo Bufalino, ho letto:

> Il fatto è che Sebastiano aveva una voce balorda. Con toni rustici e rochi, fra cui, a bruciapelo, proprio nei momenti di maggiore concitazione, scoppiava un tremito, un dubbio,
>   che si propagava alle ultime sillabe, facendole impennarsi come cavalli alla Croce di Sant’Andrea, sì da suscitare in chi l’ascoltava il sorriso, e in lui parlante un intasamento che diventava domanda, quando non si
>   liberava in un’eruzione di **sacramenti** grandiosi.

La mia domanda è sul significato di questi "sacramenti" che appaiono in nel passaggio sopra citato. Potrebbe trattarsi di schizzi di saliva involontari? O il senso è invece quello di un'[imprecazione blasfema](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/sacramento) che ho trovato in alcuni dizionari?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Il senso di ***sacramento*** che si adatta al contesto da te indicato è il secondo, cioè imprecazioni blasfeme, ed ha una valenza per lo più popolare e regionale.

Su Treccani per [sacramentare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sacramentare/):

> b. pop. Bestemmiare, imprecare: *inveiva e sacramentava come un
>   forsennato; comincio a sacramentargli contro* (I. Calvino).